# Where can I get fresh routing registry data for IP:ASN and AS lookups?

Tags: routing, whois, bgp

I'm interested in maintaining a copy of the type of data available at ftp://ftp.arin.net/pub/rr/arin.db however the arin.db file seems to be missing quite a few resources which **are** available via the ARIN [Whois-RWS](http://whois.arin.net/ui/advanced.jsp) search.

While it isn't out of the question to query ARIN whenever a lookup needs to be performed, I'd really prefer to have the source data.

Given the number of other sites which appear to have access to a more complete and accurate copy of the routing registry data, am I looking in the wrong place or do I need to pay/register to get accurate data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given the number of other sites which appear to have access to a more complete and accurate copy of the routing registry data, am I looking in the wrong place or do I need to pay/register to get accurate data?

No, you can't get it unless you fit the qualifications for a bulk whois from arin:

> ARIN provides access to a bulk copy of all objects in the ARIN Whois directory service to support the work of bona fide academic researchers, and to operators and researchers who are using the data to provide a clear benefit to the broader networking community. ARIN does not provide bulk copies of Whois data to operators who wish to incorporate this data into products, services, or internal systems with no clear benefit to the broader community.

What the other sites are doing is querying [ARIN's API](https://www.arin.net/resources/whoisrws/index.html)